# to match a string inside if condition

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop

I have a file `some_file.txt` with following contents:

```
APC000101052019
APC000201052019
APC000301052019
APC000401052019
APC000501052019
```

Now i'm tring to match `APC0001` with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /home/xxxx/xxxx/some_file.txt|while read -r line
do
    if [[ "APC0001" =~ "$line" ]]
    then
        echo $line
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

But i'm not getting the expected output, below is the output i'm getting:

```
+ cat /home/xxxx/xxxx/some_file.txt
+ read -r line
+ [[ APC0001 =~ APC000101052019]]
+ read -r line
+ [[ APC0001 =~ APC000201052019]]
+ read -r line
+ [[ APC0001 =~ APC000301052019]]
+ read -r line
+ [[ APC0001 =~ APC000401052019]]
+ read -r line
+ [[ APC0001 =~ APC000501052019]]
+ read -r line
```

What wrong i'm doing in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern to be matched should be at the right side of the `=~` expression:

```
if [[ "$line" =~ ^APC0001 ]]
    then
        echo $line
        exit 1
    fi
```

Take a look at `[[...]]` section in [bash manual/conditional constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs).

And as a sidenote, you don't need `cat` there. Just do:

```
while read -r line
do
    # ...
done < /home/xxxx/xxxx/some_file.txt
```